# In the middle of depletion layer of reverse biased p-n junction is the electric field almost zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, fusion

My textbook states:

> Due to reverse biasing the width of the depletion region increases and
>   current flowing through the diode is almost zero. In this case
>   electric field is almost zero at the middle of the depletion region.

However, I don't agree with this because even when reverse biased an electric field should exist from n side to the p side as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/6Ew3I_52CKg?t=3m) . Why should the value of this electric field be almost 0 ?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's because electric field is inversely proportional to width of the region. For example, if the potential is linearly changing, then $E=\Delta\phi/w$.

Comment: @Ruslan Ah, that does make sense. Thank you. If emf is $V$ then $E=\frac{V}{d}$. Since, $V$ must stay constant, if $d$ increases $E$ decreases. :)

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense - you are adding the reverse bias. Assuming constant doping levels on both sides, the depletion width will increase proportionally to your applied voltage. That textbook is quite wrong. It would also imply that an electron-hole pair generated in the middle would have no reason to separate and be swept out of the depletion region, which goes against every photodiode (reverse biased!) I've ever used...

Comment: @JonCuster 1) The applied voltage is constant 2) The books says that the electric field will be almost zero and not exactly 0 3) Depletion layer in reverse bias is much larger compared to forward bias.

Comment: Whether the applied voltage is constant or not is irrelevant. There is an electric field across the depletion region. Period. And the depletion region is wider with reverse bias because you have added to the potential. Go back to how a junction forms in the first place and what the fields look like. Now think what really changes when you add a little more bias.

Comment: @JonCuster I do agree with the point you are trying to make. However, let us wait for some more people to comment/answer :). Personally, I'm new to this topic so I don't have much idea about the technicalities.

Comment: Simple question: is there an electric field in the middle of a unbiased depletion region? The answer to that question should be quite clear, and is not derived from trying to build consensus. You have changed your mind several times in the comments now. Go back and do the physics and determine the actual answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54570/discussion-between-mystic-and-jon-custer).

Comment: I have said multiple times that the electric field won't be exactly $0$ at the middle. However, it will be significantly less compared to the forward bias condition.
**Simple question: is there an electric field in the middle of a unbiased depletion region** ? The answer is **yes**. @JonCuster

Comment: What is "almost" zero?  What is "almost" for one process might be large for another.    The statement is vague enough to be meaningless.

Comment: @garyp Yeah, I agree with you and JonCuster. I got it now. Thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: Don't delete it.  You had a question, we had a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am correct but what I think is that during  reverse bias the charge carriers move in the direction opposite to what they have during diffusion. So, in a way they are undoing the diffusion causing the fixed acceptor and donar ions be not fixed any more (because the fixed ions are due to interaction with the oppositely charged carrier which are in minority in respective side, and reverse saturation current is nothing but the movement of these to their original side). So the electric field in a way diminishes approximately to zero and charge carriers move with the support of external source.